# Splitting Field of $p(x) = (x^4-1)(x^3-2)$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I found the splitting field of a polynomial $p(x)=(x^4-1)(x^3-2)$ to be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega,i)$ where $ \omega=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, but is it possible to simplify this field?

Comment: Don't know if simpler, but you could replace $\omega$ with $\sqrt[3]{3}$

Comment: I don't understand, why $\sqrt[3]{3}$?

Comment: Oops meant $\sqrt{3}$ not cuberoot.

Comment: Diego-- If you saw my correction to $\sqrt{3},$ does using it simplify the extension in your opinion?

Comment: I wanted a way to write the extension in terms of two elements and not three

Answer (score 3):

The primitive element theorem says *every* finite extension of $\mathbf Q$ can be generated by a single element (called a primitive element).  For "random" examples, the sum typically works. And this is such a case: $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega,i) = \mathbf Q\mathbf(\sqrt[3]{2}+\omega+i)$, but the minimal polynomial over $\mathbf Q$ for $\sqrt[3]{2}+\omega+i$ is very ugly. Using a computer, here it is:
$$
x^{12} + 6x^{11} + 27x^{10} + 72x^9 + 150x^8 + 258x^7 + 395x^6 + 348x^5 - 54x^4 - 558x^3 - 417x^2 + 96x + 277.
$$
I do not regard this as simpler.  The field is better viewed with the $3$ generators you gave.